# unable to link gitlab services to own container in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a simple .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind
  - postgres:9.5

stages:
- build
- test

variables:
  STAGING_REGISTRY: "dhub.example.com"
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: ${STAGING_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}:latest


before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci -p $DHUB_PASSWORD $STAGING_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE -f Dockerfile-dev .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run --env-file=.environment --link=postgres:db $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE nosetests
```

Everything works fine until the actual test stage. In test I'm unable to access my postgres service.
`docker: Error response from daemon: Could not get container for postgres.`

I tried to write test like this:

```
test1:
  stage: test
  image: $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
  services:
    - postgres:9.5
  script:
    - python manage.py test
```

But in this case, I'm unable to pull this image, because of authentication:

`ERROR: Preparation failed: unauthorized: authentication required`

Am I missing something?